# Input.TextInputListener brings up Navigation bar but doesn't get rid of it

Tags: java, android, libgdx

My game is set to immersive mode using the Application Config `(config.useImmersiveMode = true)`.
Also, in my game, I implement `Input.TextInputListener` in order to get some user input. However, when someone activates the `TextInputListener`, the navigation bar comes up, and stays even after they exit out of the `TextInputListener`. How would I set it to re-hide the navigation bar whenever the user navigates out of the `TextInputListener`?

Here is my game so you can see the issue yourself:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samuel.doubledodge

The `TextInputListener` should come up the first time you start the game, and you can manually make it come up by pressing the "Change name" button on the Game Over screen.

Thanks

Comment: I've tested your App on marshmallow, navigation bar automatically hide when i exit TextInputListener. On which OS you're facing this issue ?

Comment: Amazon Fire tablet. Maybe its specific to FireOS. Good to know that it works on Android OS devices. Thanks for the help.